# GCP python error: "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file" while creating teamdrive

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to create a team drive using the google drive api after the migration of the teamdrives collection to drives. but I had an error of permission.

```
@endpoints.method(
    TEAM_DRIVE_RESOURCE,
    TeamDriveMessage,
    path='create',
    http_method='POST',
    name='create')
def create_team_drive(self, request):
    try:
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        team_drive_service = Services().get_team_drive_service()
        request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        response_team_drive = team_drive_service.drives().create(
            body={"name": request.customerName + " | " + request.appName,
                  }, requestId=request_id).execute()
        logger.info(response_team_drive)
    except HttpError as error:
        if error.resp.status < 500:
            raise endpoints.BadRequestException(error._get_reason())
        raise endpoints.InternalServerErrorException(error._get_reason())
    return TeamDriveMessage(teamDriveId=response_team_drive.id)
```

here is the code of getting the service of the team drive

```
@staticmethod
def get_team_drive_service():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly'])
    team_drive_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    return team_drive_service
```

**error message:**

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
  }
}

[permissions assigned to the account service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR9yL.png)

Comment: Did you setup Domain-Wide Delegation? What permissions are assigned to the service account and where did you assign them? Why do you have so many scopes? Pick the one you need and remove the others. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth Then post the complete error message.

Comment: Yes I setup the Domain-Wide Delegation. I assigned permissions in the Google Admin. The error message: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
  }
}